# How to crack base conversion that uses a secret symbol set?

Tags: encryption, encoding

I've looked at [this crypto SE post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35678/numeric-base-conversion-in-cryptosystems) but it doesn't address the **how** of my question.

---

I've been interested in cryptography for some time. I wrote a relatively basic cryptosystem in Python that uses base conversion as one of its layers of security (I don't actually use it for anything, don't worry). I've heard time and time again that encoding is not encryption, and in its most basic form, I understand this completely. But **why** is it still not encryption if we use a secret symbol set?

### Example

We can easily convert from decimal to hex because we know that the decimal symbols are `0123456789` in that order, and the hex symbols are `0123456789ABCDEF` in that order. There is no encryption in this. But what if we shuffled the hex symbols? Like so:

$$\\\\$$

Decimal plaintext: `69420`

Shuffled hex symbols: `87FC9ED61543B20A` **(secret!)**

Encode using shuffled hex symbols: `69420 -> 78AFB`

$$\\\\$$

If you didn't know the shuffled hex symbol set, how would you crack this encoding? In this case we have $16! \approx 10^{13}$ possible hex symbol sets which is not hard to brute-force.

> **EDIT:** Actually I realized we can extract the hex symbols by incrementing the plaintext by 1 and encoding 16 times, but anyway later we shuffle the plaintext symbols which I think destroys the ability to "increment by 1" - correct me if I'm wrong.

But what if our encoding used larger symbol sets, AND we also shuffle the plaintext symbols before encoding?

For example, if we're encoding from the first 256 Unicode symbols to the 94 printable non-whitespace ASCII symbols, then the number of possible ciphertext symbol sets is $94! \approx 10^{146}$ which *is* difficult to brute-force; and if we shuffle the 256 Unicode symbols before encoding, it adds another obstacle. How would one crack this?

### The big question

I know base conversion is slow. I'm not asking why it's not practical, I'm asking how the above system can be cracked mathematically/algorithmically without knowing the **key**, which is the **orderings of the ciphertext and plaintext symbol sets**.

---

P.S.

My humble Python cryptosystem, which is very similar to the one described above, if you're curious: https://github.com/SamerN88/DRE.94

Comment: Well, start reading a basic cryptography book. You reinvented the [Substitution cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher) which is broken 1000 years ago by frequency analysis.

Comment: @kelalaka Base conversion is not the same as substitution cipher, hence basic frequency analysis would not work. Test it yourself. The most basic way to see this is like this: $$\text{hex}(111111111111) = \text{19DEBD01C7}$$ Clearly the high frequency of 1s was not reflected at all in the output. I took a cryptography course that covered substitution ciphers and frequency analysis (among other things like RSA, Diffie-Hellman, etc.), but it was more or less introductory. That's the extent of my knowledge.

Comment: @kelalaka I imagine a way one can apply frequency analysis on base conversion is by encoding the ciphertext using any symbol set ***as long as it has the same base as the original plaintext***. Then just apply normal frequency analysis. But this assumes you know the base of the plaintext symbol set.

Comment: Base conversion does not prevent attackers - they can find some way to bypass it, what would you do against known-plaintext attackers that can easily reveal your key?

Comment: @kelalaka I never claimed base conversion prevents attackers, obviously this isn't an unbreakable system. My question asks *how* would one attack the system I described without knowing the key. You mentioned known-plaintext attack, sure, but that assumes you have a known plaintext. And still, I think you'd need to know the base of the plaintext, although I could be wrong there. What if you don't have any of that?

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions**

You should assume that the attacker knows the algorithm and the only unknown is the key. In your case they key can be a combination of the base and the substitution table.

You should assume that the attacker can apply your encryption to any messages the attackers wants (e.g. the attacker tricks you out to encrypt some specific messages) and knows the encryption results.

Why are they important? Because cryptography is usually required in real life cases, e.g. when millions of messages need to be encrypted. And if the data are of big importance, the attacker finds usually ways to know about the software and hardware a lot of everything. And the only unknown part remains the key.

If you say these assumptions do not hold, then the question not about mathematics and cryptographic algorithms, and thus it is off topic on this.

**Chosen-plaintext attack**

The attacker creates some random message and applies your encryption. Then changes a single bit in the original message and applies your encryption. According to your algorithm a single bit in the resulting message will be changed. Then the attacker changes the 2nd bit and applies the encryption.  again. And so on. If the changed bits in the encrypted message are close to each other within let say 5 bits, the base is 32. If there will be groups of 6 bits, the base is 64, etc. Thus the base will be detected after a very small number of operations.

After the base is determined, then only a single step more is needed. The attacker will create a message consisting of all possible values in the given base and encrypt it. The encrypted message will be actually the substitution table.

Comment: I need some clarification. When you say change a bit then change the 2nd bit, do you mean **flip** the 1st bit of the plaintext and encrypt, then go back to the **original** plaintext and flip only the 2nd bit and encrypt, then flip only the 3rd bit and encrypt, etc...? Also, when you say the base is revealed, which base are you referring to? The plaintext is treated as a base-M number and the ciphertext is treated as a base-N number, as this is base conversion from M to N. Which base is revealed, M or N? Remember, $M≠N$.

Comment: 1) I mean flipping the bit in the original message: Original message with flipped 1st bit, original message with flipped 2nd bit etc.

Comment: 2) The original message is just a sequence of bits. It does not depend on any base. The word "base" makes only sense for interpretation or transformation of data. If you apply base 16, you will get representation of the original message as a hexadecimal digits. If you apply base 256, you will get representation as ASCII characters, etc. If your transformation includes 2 bases - split the sequence of bits into groups according to base M and transform using base N - this does not change anything in the attack. It will just take a bit more tests, but will be still very quick.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm sure you're right, but I'm just not seeing it. I understand that the message is just a sequence of bits independent of base; but to even have a notion of base conversion, we need agreed-upon symbol sets. If we don't know the symbol sets, we can't encode, and that's where I have trouble reconciling your attack. Let me give you an example and you show me step by step how to crack it. I will try to use simplified parameters (see next comment).

Comment: Our key is both the plaintext & ciphertext symbol sets. Let's say we convert from hex to decimal:$$\\$$
Standard hex symbol set: `0123456789ABCDEF`$$\\$$
Shuffled hex symbol set: `D934CA26B71805EF` (1st part of key)$$\\$$
Standard decimal symbol set: `0123456789`$$\\$$
Shuffled decimal symbol set: `9716403258` (2nd part of key)$$\\$$
Key: `(D934CA26B71805EF, 9716403258)` **(secret!)** $$\\$$
Plaintext (hex): `ABC123`$$\\$$
*ENCRYPT - convert using key symbol sets:* $$\\$$
Ciphertext (decimal): `5786210`$$\\$$
Since this is a known-plaintext attack, the plaintext is not secret.

Comment: **EDIT:** I made a mistake; the ciphertext is not `5786210`, it should be `0253179`.

Comment: In your example you contradict to yourself. When you transform A, you get 5, where as according to your substitution it should be 1. For hexadecimal numbers you do inverse substitution. For decimal number you do normal substitution. But for the solution it does not matter.

Comment: Now write a program that shows you bit representation of the original number and bit representation of the resulting number. Then flip the 1st bit in the original number, do your substitutions and print the bit representation of the result. Then flip the 2nd bit of the original number, do your substitutions and again print the bit representation of the result. And so on. Then you will see patterns.

Comment: I did not contradict myself. I think you're mistaken about the system I've described. As I mentioned multiple times, this is not generic substitution. `A` is a digit, or a number. Therefore the digit `A` doesn't "transform" consistently like a basic substitution, so it won't transform to `1` all the time. And actually, if you encoded `A` by itself, it would transform to `0`, not `1`. So I think you've misinterpreted the system.

Comment: Moreover, you asked me to write the bit representation (binary form) of the original number and the encrypted number. To even suggest this implies that we know the symbol sets of `ABC123` and `0253179`, which are `D934CA26B71805EF` and `9716403258` respectively; the attacker doesn't know these. If you're asking me to just use the standard hex and decimal symbols, i.e. `0123456789ABCDEF` and `0123456789`, then I don't see how this would help since they are just some arbitrary base-16 and base-10 symbol sets that don't relate to this particular system.

Comment: Furthermore, just to make sure, I assumed that you wanted me to use the standard symbol sets. So I converted `ABC123` to binary using the **standard hex symbol set**, flipped the 1st bit, and converted back to hex, which of course gave me `ABC122`. Then I encrypted this and got `0253174`, then I converted this to binary using the **standard decimal symbol set** and got `111101110011110110`. I did this again with the 2nd bit, and the final binary result was `111101110011110111`. Results:

Comment: $$
\text{plaintext converted to binary: } 101010111100000100100011 \\
\text{ } \\
111101110011111011 \\
111101110011110110 \\
111101110011110111 \\
\text{ } \\
\text{(1st line: ciphertext converted to binary)} \\
\text{(2nd line: flip 1st bit in plaintext, then encrypt)} \\
\text{(3rd line: flip 2nd bit in plaintext, then encrypt)} \\
$$

Comment: If you notice, the second one has 3 bits changed from the first, and the third one has 1 bit changed from the second. This isn't what your attack promised. So I really don't think you meant to convert `ABC123` and `0253179` to bit representation using the **standard** symbol sets. So I ask, ***how exactly would one convert `ABC123` and `0253179` to their bit representations?*** $$ \ $$ Finally, I do not know what you mean by "For hexadecimal numbers you do inverse substitution. For decimal number you do normal substitution." In fact, I don't even know what you mean by "substitution" anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139709/discussion-between-mentallurg-and-snn).